# Show multiple ordered products and qty based on ID in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Here is my code for the API

```
public function show_ordered_products($order_id){
       $fetchedit = DB::table('orders')
       ->leftJoin('product_orders', 'product_orders.orders_id', '=', 'orders.id')
       ->leftJoin('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_orders.product_id')
       ->where('orders.id', $order_id)
       ->select('products.name as product_name', 'product_orders.quantity as quantity')
       ->get();
       return response()->json(['ShowProduct' => $fetchedit], 200);
   }
```

my problem is that i dont know how to use it for web controller and display it on my modal

it should display the product names and quantity ordered by the user

here is my modal code

```html
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-default2">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">View Order</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                        <th>Products</th>
                        <th style="width: 100px">Quantity</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" id="edit-id">
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="edit-product" style="background: transparent; border: none;"></td>
                        <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="edit-qty" style="background: transparent; border: none;"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is my route in api.php

```
Route::get('orders/ordered_products/{order_id}',[ApiOrdersController::class, 'show_ordered_products']);
```

and this is my route in web.php

```
Route::get('orders/ordered-products', [OrdersController::class, 'show_ordered_products'])->name('show_ordered_products');
```

Comment: did you tried by fetch data throw api (ajax)?

Comment: no sir/ma'am @hasan05

Comment: then, how are you trying to bring the info to the blade? 
by the way, I hope this query output is ok as your desired. I mean, no problem with query. right?

Comment: yes there is no problem in my query, it works fine in postman. i just dont know how to use it in web controller to show the info into blade @hasan05

Comment: I think you dont know how to use xhr/ajax call. I think this simple ajax tutorial will help to understand, how ajax call works. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm